# Django: reuse app in different django versions

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to reuse an app on 2 different django versions and I'm receiving a lot of ImportError exceptions due to the different django versions.

I basically need to retrieve some info from external app, is there any nice way to do so or I would need to create an API for it?

Comment: Your question is too vague. What are the Django versions? What are the failing imports. The Django deprecation policy means that if your app works with Django 1.8 LTS without deprecation warnings it should work with Django 1.9. 1.10 and 1.11 LTS. To span other Django versions, you might need `try.. except` blocks for the imports.

Comment: the gap is too wide, 1.6 and 1.10
Is there any other solution? I think to communicate via API.

Comment: As I said before, you haven't provided enough details.